# Count number of times variable value is 0

Tags: arrays, swift

I have my json output from server

```
posts =     (
            {
         address = "";
        "key_number" = A80;
        name = "";
        Id = 103;
        visited = 1;
    },
            {
       address = "";
       key_number = K3;
       name = "";
       Id = 110;
       visited = 0;
    },
     {
       address = "";
       key_number = B67;
       name = "";
       Id = 109;
       visited = 0;
    }
);
```

I want to get the total count  where visited = 0 .
How is it possible in swift code?

Comment: what is your Question didn't get you can you explain more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter` with your array and find the count.

```
let posts = yourJson["posts"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
let filterPostsCount = posts.filter { $0["visited"] as? Int == 0 }.count
print(filterPostsCount)
```

Comment: I am getting filterPostsCount value  0 always

Comment: @SwiftUser Edit your question with your current code also you have added response from Xcode console so may be `visited` is String not `Int` try once `let filterPostsCount = posts.filter { $0["visited"] as? String == "0" }.count`